# How to control the query limit and the sort order of the android searchview?

Tags: android, limit, searchview

I hope I can change the query limit and the sort order of the android searchview, then I have changed the query method in my ExampleSearchRecentSuggestionsProvider, but nothing happend.

```
public class ExampleSearchSuggestionProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {
public final static String AUTHORITY = "com.example.ExampleSearchSuggestionProvider";

public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;

public ExampleSearchSuggestionProvider() {
    setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
}

public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
        String sortOrder) {
    uri = uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("limit", "3").build();
    sortOrder = " DESC";
    return super.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/menu_search_hint"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.ExampleSearchRecentSuggestionsProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?" >
</searchable>
```

I added "limit=3" in the uri(uri = uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("limit", "3").build();
), but the cursor result was not limited by 3, the cursor returned all the results.
I set the order to "DESC", but the results were not ordered.

Thank you.

Comment: limit=3 is wrong i think.. try to change 'limit 3' .

Comment: But what I added is "uri = uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("limit", "3").build();", I have no way to change 'limit 3', could you give me some advice?